# Why would I NOT want to use inverse_of everywhere?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rails-activerecord

As outlined here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

inverse_of appears to tell Rails to Cache the in memory associations and minimize Database Queries. Their example is:

```
 class Dungeon < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :traps, :inverse_of => :dungeon
   has_one :evil_wizard, :inverse_of => :dungeon
 end

 class Trap < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :dungeon, :inverse_of => :traps
 end
```

Which they immediatly follow with:

```
 for `belongs_to` associations `has_many` inverse associations are ignored.
```

So I have several questions.

1. Are inverse associations ignored on `has_many` for a `belongs_to`? If so, how does their example make sense? Shouldn't it just not do anything?
2. As far as I can tell (assuming it does anything) All this allows to do is something like:

   ```
   dungeon.traps.first.dungeon
   ```

   with the final call to `.dungeon` NOT generating an entire new query, but merely reaching for the in memory association. Assuming that is correct, why would I ever NOT want that behavior? Why wouldn't I just stick `inverse_of:` on every association?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I started writing about rails inflector and how when an association isn't a straight inflection of a model you use inverse_of to indicate what it is. But then I scrolled to the section you mention and this is how I see it. Say you have something like:

```
# let's pick a dungeon
d = Dungeon.first

# say you find also find a trap that belongs to this particular d
t = Trap.find(...)

# then t.dungeon is the exact same object as d
d == t.dungeon
```

Of course `dungeon.traps.first.dungeon` doesn't really make sense and I doubt that's why this exists. Personally I don't see where and how I would use this but the example they give seems to fill a use case. It goes like this:

```
# you have an attribute level on dungeon
d.level # => 5

# now say you have a comparison after a modification to level
d.level = 10

# now without inverse_of the following thing occurs
d.level         # => 10
t.dungeon.level # => 5

# d was updated and since t.dungeon is a whole different object 
# it doesn't pick up the change and is out of sync but using invers_of you get
d.level         # => 10
t.dungeon.level # => 10

# because d and t.dungeon are the very same object
```

Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: so does that mean that if I were to say t.dungeon.level = 10 (instead of d.level = 10), that d.level would not get updated even if i set inverse_of because it was ignored? and generally, updating a member of a collection won't sync to other instances of that member? but it still doesn't seem to cause a problem to put inverse_of everywhere, at least in the hopes that they do support it eventually, right?

Comment: @bdwain this is very interesting to me, as I always kind of thought that Rails inferred this `inverse_of` relationship automatically (if names matched). After coming upon this recently (while doing validations on a model that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` a related model), I have to agree with your conclusion: use `inverse_of` generously. I cannot imagine any reason not to.

Answer (score 4):

Great news! In Rails 4.1 basic associations* will **automatically** set up `inverse_of`.

*More convenience means more edge cases...
automatic inverse_of *only* works for associations that do ***not*** specify any of the following options:

- `:through`
- `:foreign_key`
- `:conditions`
- `:polymorphic`

Resources:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html
http://wangjohn.github.io/activerecord/rails/associations/2013/08/14/automatic-inverse-of.html

Comment: "Not for `:conditions`" in the manual isn't entirely correct, it should be "Not if `scope` is defined".